# What is my uninitialized struct value?

Tags: c

So  i have two structs in the global section

```
typedef struct stack_1
 {
  short ctr;
 } stack_1;

typedef struct stack_2
 {
   struct stack_1 *s1;
 } stack_2;
```

then later in the code i do

```
struct stack_2 *x;
```

what  is my x initialized to ?? 0 or Null. Thank you in advance.

Comment: where in the code, local or global.

Comment: Who knows? most likely it's pointing at nasal daemons.

Comment: the struct stack_2 *x; is local in the code.

Comment: @ken, now it's definitely pointing at nasal daemons.. ;)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If your declaration is outside any function or with the `static` keyword (more precisely, has static storage duration), the initial value of x is a null pointer (which may be written either as `0` or as `NULL`).  If it's inside a function and not defined as `static` (i.e., has automatic storage duration), its initial value is garbage.

Comment: Static storage duration can also be inside a function.

Comment: @Eric: Good point, updated.  (I intended the phrase "more precisely" to cover that, but I should have been more explicit.)

Answer (score 0):

After the local variable declaration

```
struct stack_2 *x;
```

`x` is an uninitialized (dangling) pointer. It has garbage value, pointing to some random location in memory. Dereferencing it would be *undefined behaviour*, i.e. something you should avoid at all costs.

Comment: You should always do struck stack_2 *x = NULL; or some such.

Comment: Unless it has static storage duration, in which case it is initialized to 0 (aka NULL)

Comment: @bdonlan, the OP stated that it is a local variable.

Comment: You don't *always* need to initialize it; for example, if you do `some_type *ptr; if (something) ptr = this; else ptr = that;`.  Though some would argue that always initializing is good style anyway.

Comment: @mydogisbox: No, you should just understand pointers before using them. Nonsense initialization with NULL actually **hides bugs** (the compiler can no longer warn you if you use the variable without *actually* initializing it) and makes the reader question why you included "dead code" in your program (maybe there's some case where the initial value was actually used?)

Answer (score 0):

- If the declaration is local , then `x` holds garbage value
- If the declaration is global, then `x` holds 0

Answer (score 0):

Since you've `typedef`'d the structure name you should instantiate it as follows:

```
stack_2 *x;
```

The value of `x` depends on where the above code is located. If it is global `x` will be set to 0. If it is a local variable within a function `x` will be uninitialized.

Comment: It's legal to refer to the type either as `struct stack_2` or as `stack_2`.  But if you're going to call it `struct stack_2` anyway, the `typedef` isn't useful.

Comment: @Keith Thompson I know either way is legal, that's why I said *should* instead of *must* :-)

Comment: My own preference would be to drop the `typedef` and refer to the type as `struct stack_2`.